# Hold notifications received by device

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to be able to get notifications before they are displayed to the user, save them and show them at some chosen time.

I tried the [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) but i can only get the notification after it already displayed.

Is there any way to do it?

Also is there a way to block notifications from speciffic apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want to be able to get notifications before they are displayed to the user, save them and show them at some chosen time.**

-> you can get notification that are arrived with `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)`
you also can save them and you can show them at your desired time by creating a service and by building this notification again.

**I tried the NotificationListenerService but i can only get the notification after it already displayed.**

-> NotificationListenerService will give you notification information that are arriving. You can't block notification but you can remove the particular notification by getting its id or groupkey from notification stack.

**Also is there a way to block notifications from speciffic apps?**

-> No you can't block notification from arriving, though you can remove all notification, same way as i have mentioned above, which are not in your list of apps.

**Edit**
All these can be done in API >=19 only.

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: This is actually my first approach but there are issues with relaunching canceled notification

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), you can save to a DB or Shared Preferences and comment out the line that displays the notification to the user. Then, you can use a background service to display it to the user whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Update to @kiturk3 answer :

**Also is there a way to block notifications from speciffic apps?**

From Lollipop, this can be done. User can block notification from perticular package of application

> Settings -> Sound and Notification -> Application Notification ->
>   Click on any application -> Select Block

Furthermore, User can give Importance to specific application notification using `priority`, while showing on `Lockscreen`

Comment: yes @Kushal it can be done. But at development level we have to get it done by coding. I suggested that with code only :)
cheers...